# Getting coordinates for many addresses with one request (Google API, iPhone)

Tags: iphone, geolocation

How can I get the geographical coordinates for multiple addresses in one request from Google's API in an iPhone app?

I would prefer a JSON response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to take a look to the new `CLGeocoder` class(iOS5) in the "[Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/UsingGeocoders/UsingGeocoders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH4-SW1)", go to the last part, you can see the snippet for the Forward Geocoding to translate addresses to coordinates, with blocks.